# preg_match problem

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have index.html

`<html>
    <head>
        bla bla bla
    </head>
    <body class="someclass">
        bla bla bla
    </body>
</html>`

I need get content inside body tag. Tried this

```
<?php $site = file_get_contents("index.html"); preg_match("/<body[^>]*>(.*?) \/body>/is", $site, $matches); print ($matches[1]); ?>
```

But it not output to anything. Please tell me problem here. Thank you.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$site = file_get_contents("index.html"); 
preg_match("/<body.*?>(.*?)<\/body>/is", $site, $matches); 
print ($matches[1]); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be not your answer but i recommend you to try php DOMDocument [link](http://www.php.net/DomDocument)

Answer (score 0):

`"/<body[^>]*>(.*?) \/body>/is"` Should be `"/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/is"`

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can get the body with something like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('index.html')
$body = $html->find('body');
```

you can then get the inner HTML by:

```
$content = $body->innertext;
```

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).